# CakePHP append URL

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a cakePHP script running on my server - unfortunately though I encounter severe ISP cache therefore I've seen to append an URL to some URLs as below:

```
    <h2><?php echo $this->Html->link('Clients', array('controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'index?nc='.time().'')); ?></h2></div></div>
```

By adding **?nc='.time().'** the URL automatically appends a timestamp which helps me avoid the ISP cache issue. e.g. **/clients/index?nc=1364619426**

While I figured out how to make this work on some URLs I do not seem to obtain this result on others. I have this data-table which lists all my clients with an ending View / Edit link button. Please see below:

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('View/Edit', array('action' => 'view', $client['Client']['id']), array('class' => 'view')); ?>
```

Once this button is clicked and the page opens the URL structure is: **/clients/view/1**

What's the best way to implement the previously mentioned **?nc='.time().'** into this url? My ideal goal is to have this URL looking like **/clients/view/1?nc=1364619426**

Some expert advise would be really helpful since I am very new to CakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('View/Edit', array('action' => 'view', $client['Client']['id']), "?" => array('nc' => time(), array('class' => 'view')); ?>
```

Comment: Wow - thank you very much @castis - this is fantastic and it seems to work just fine. I've noted that the URL though, or to be more specific the "?" results in clients/view/1/%3Fnc%3D1364620127 - is there a way to preserve the ? symbol? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh man, my apologies, what i put doesnt work. i have edited my answer to what is correct.

Comment: Dear @castis - absolutely no need to apologize as I would be stuck without your help :) While the previous code you've posted worked fine (except the ? symbol) this new one results in a syntax error. I've used  <?php echo $this->Html->link('View/Edit', array('action' => 'view', $client['Client']['id'], "?" => array('nc' => time()), array('class' => 'view')); ?>

Comment: Whoops again. Moved my ')' from after time()) to after 'view' in the example

Comment: Thank you castis - sorry but I did not entirely understand your reply - what exactly do I need to change?

Comment: Oh, i changed my example. You should be abke to recopy it.

Comment: I still see the previous version with the syntax error, in any case though thank you very much, for the time being I will stick with the first version then. Have a nice day